# docker-compose up/down just one container

Tags: docker

I have not been able to find a way to up/down just one container in a docker-compose.yml file. I can off-course start and stop a single container, but I cannot make changes to a containers configuration between restarts (environment variables, mount points etc.)

What am I missing here? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: ```docker-compose build <service-name>``` followed by ```docker-compose up```. This would only build the changes to a single container instead of rebuilding all the containers

Comment: I don't have your use case. I just have several containers running and I want to stop one. Apparently there is no way to do this. I ended up stopping everything and restarting them all minus the one. Seems mildly ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this need recently and solved it by having a separate `docker-compose-production.yml` file to deal with tweaks. Then remember to launch with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml...`

Comment: How does this work when it comes time to do `docker-compose down`? Wouldn't it bring down all the containers which have been brought up in all .yml files?

Comment: You can do `docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml down`

Comment: And where do you specify the container you would like to get up/down? `-f` is the selector of compose file, not container.

Comment: ... "by having a separate  .yml file."   Yes, it's not an ideal solution but it deletes not only volumes but also a network, which  "docker-compose rm -s -v yourService" won't do, according to what I understand.

Answer (score 161):

I found this to have the same affect as docker-compose down for a single service:

`docker-compose rm -s -v yourService`

[`docker-compose rm`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/)

> Usage: rm [options] [SERVICE...]
>
> Options:
> -s, --stop    Stop the containers, if required, before removing
> -v            Remove any anonymous volumes attached to containers

You can condense all the flags into a single `-` param: `docker-compose rm -sv yourService`

Comment: I think disposes the disk, btw

Comment: Could you please explain the flags, what they would do?

Comment: Jordan Morris, according to the manual -v disposes of anonymous volumes only when used with 'rm'. When used with 'down' it is stronger, also disposing of named volumes. The former is pretty safe.

Comment: This should be the answer. docker-compose down only does all or nothing...this points to the service and stops it.

Comment: @eco and importantly, docker-compose down applies to all the containers, not just one

Comment: This doesn't work with named volumes. rm -v only removes anonymous volumes.

Comment: I was looking for this solution exactly. Only thing is I had to execute `docker-compose rm -s -v yourService` twice. First time it stops service's container. Second time it asks `? Going to remove name-service-1` which I responded yes and container is removed along with unnamed volumes, being able to apply fresh start recreating unnamed volumes again with `docker-compose up -d yourService`. This is without affecting other services being stoped, which `docker-compose down` does. Thanks!

Comment: Hm... Not sure why it doesn't work for me. The console says "No stopped containers". Docker Compose version v2.12.0.

Comment: If you don't want to enter the confirmation for `? Going to remove <service_name>`, just add -f

Answer (score 61):

I would suggest you check out [this excellent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466428/how-to-restart-a-single-container-with-docker-compose) on stackoverflow.com. The quick answer here to rebuild the single container and restart it is:

```
docker-compose up -d --build worker
```

This would be the ideal solution if, for example, your changes involved your Dockerfile and not just docker-compose.ymll

Comment: I wish I'd seen this before. This is the correct answer!! In any case I've created my version, which will probably get triaged and deprecated with a step by step explanation.

Comment: Almost the correct answer, since this says how to bring *up* one container. The question is also about how to bring one container *down*. However, that seems to be only possible with `docker rm`

Comment: Mmm ran this command, replacing `worker` with the service name, but it just rebuilt *all* services...  I guess `worker` was supposed to be literal? I am just looking for a set of commands to bring one service down, then bring one service back up...

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up yourService
```

to start just yourService and all dependencies required by it.

So if yourService depends on mysql container, the above command would start both the containers.

Answer (score 7):

Others have shown how to start/up containers together, however this is how you can restart and stop them individually.

**Restart a Container**

```
# restart immediately
docker-compose restart <container_name>

# restart after a 10s delay
docker-compose restart -t 10 <container_name>
```

**Stop a Container**

```
# stop immediately  
docker-compose stop <container_name>

# stop after a 10s delay  
docker-compose stop -t 10 <container_name>
```

For those who want to make changes without downtime, you can build a new image and make changes without any stop/start with the following command but ***it will build all Dockerfile in docker-compose.yml file***:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: This is the only real answer to the original question - using "start/stop/restart <container>".

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to delete anything.
To address the OP's question:
You need to rebuild the image then use up to replace the container with the newly configured imaged.

IMPORTANT: notice that the new image will automatically be tagged with latest.

```
Step 1: Edit Docker file
Step 2: docker-compose build
Step 3: docker-compose up
```

The docker-compose up will leave all the unchanged containers alone and replace only the containers that have a newly created image.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Jordan Morris' answer, this version of the command will take down your specific service ***and not prompt you*** before it removes the associated volumes:

```
docker-compose rm -s -v -f your_service_name
```

The difference is the addition of a `-f` flag ([for "force"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_rm/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker-compose -f your-compose-file-here.yml stop only-that-service
```